# Does add only work for fields in WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

It seems a program like this does not work.

```
   PROGRAM-ID. Test.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.

   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT CountFile ASSIGN TO "count.dat"
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.

   FD CountFile.
   01 CountDetails.
       02 FCountA          PIC 99 VALUE 0.
       02 FCountB          PIC 99 VALUE 0.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

   Begin.

       OPEN OUTPUT CountFile

       ADD 1 TO  FCountA
       ADD 1 TO  FCountB

       WRITE CountDetails
       CLOSE CountFile

       STOP  RUN.
```

This writes 9999 to the count.dat file. ADD works for fields in the  WORKING-STORAGE SECTION but not in the FILE SECTION.

Is that true ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: Is that true?
A: No, it isn't.

`ADD` works for any *numeric* field, no matter where it is stored.

Note that data in `FILE SECTION` is only guaranteed to be available at all after a successful `OPEN` (as you've mentioned GnuCOBOL: this one always provides the storage). It does not have any guaranteed value, so you likely want to `INITIALIZE` the data.

Sample COBOL sample that shows both and can be [adjusted and executed](http://tpcg.io/bUCUIUi6):

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       input-output section.
       file-control.
           select test-file
           assign to 'test-file'
           organization is line sequential.

 data division.
 file section.
       fd test-file.
           01 num-var  pic 9 value 0.
 working-storage section.
           01 num2-var  pic 9 value 0.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
ADD  1 TO num-var num2-var
DISPLAY 'Hello, num ' num2-var ' and file ' num-var.
INITIALIZE num-var num2-var
ADD  1 TO num-var num2-var
DISPLAY 'Hello, num ' num2-var ' and file ' num-var.
ADD num2-var to num-var
ADD num2-var to num-var
DISPLAY 'Hello, num ' num2-var ' and file ' num-var.
ADD num-var to num-var
DISPLAY 'Hello, num ' num2-var ' and file ' num-var.
STOP RUN.
```

Beware: it is fixed-form reference-format, not necessarily portable, the missing `OPEN` can mean it aborts - and it isn't any reasonable good style - but demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Thanks. INITIALIZE fixed it.